# How do I move data to a new version of the iOS app?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm developing an app from scratch in Xamarin that is intended to be an upgrade from an existing app developed previously in xcode and already available on the app store (I haven't seen it, but I presume it's objective c).  The new app needs to ingest data from the old app so the user transition experience is smooth. I don't currently know how the old data is stored on the iOS device, just that it is stored on the device and not in a more convenient location.

Assuming I need access to all the data the old app might have stored on the device, what are my options?  Can I release it as a separate app and somehow ingest the old data? Do I have to release it as the same app to the app store to gain access to the old data? Am I going to have to consider the harder route of updating the old app to store the data in a special way or in the cloud so the new app can then access it?

While I'm doing this is Xamarin, I'm fine with answers that discuss what Apple provides and how iOS works in this instance, and I'll figure out what that means for Xamarin, but Xamarin specific answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does you previous app, that is on the App Store uses some database ?

Comment: @UmarFarooque I don't yet know, but I suspect it does.

Comment: if your app uses the same Bundle ID as the previous app, it will have access to that apps's sandbox and prior data.  Otherwise it won't, and there really isn't any clean way to transfer the data other than adding some export mechanism to the old app.

Comment: Assuming you are using the bundle id and signing, you would have access to the "data", but the question for you would be what is the "data", obtaining access to the original ObjC/Swift code and reviewing how the data is stored would be the first thing I would do.

Comment: I agree with Jason, data saved in **userdefaults** and **document directory** should be fairly easily accessible but things like **core data and sqlite** could bring complexities.

Comment: Update the old app to upload data in the cloud could be really hard.  You should dig into the old code to know how the data was stored and try to access it with your new app (with the same bundle ID as explained above)